# stk500_recv() programmer is not responding

Tags: c++, printing, arduino, bootloader, firmware

### Intro

Yesterday we were trying to update the firmware of our 3D-printer a [Tevo Tarantula i3](https://tevo3dprinterstore.com/products/2016-newest-tevo-tarantula-i3-aluminium-extrusion-3d-printer-kit-printer-3d-printing-2-rolls-filament-8gb-sd-card-lcd-as-gift) The printer was running [Marlin 3D Printer Firmware](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula).

We installed a new module a TL-Touch Sensor, a chinese copy of the Bl-Touch an auto bedleveling touch sensor for a 3D printer.

After re-configurating a new version of the [firmware](https://github.com/r0ndL/Tevo-Tarantula-Marlin-1.1-RC7-BugFix-) for our setup in the Arduino IDE we went on with uploading the sketch to the Arduino Mega that was controling our 3D printer.

### The problems

Before we started uploading we made sure the right COM-port was selected in the Arduino IDE and that also the right type of Arduino was selected. The Arduino Mega 2260.

Then we started with compiling the firmware and then uploading it to the Mega, Somewhere in between that moment the IDE freezed and crashed. As a response we removed the USB cable that was connected from the PC uploading the firmware onto the Arduino Mega, *(This was a stupid mistake)*

After we restarted the IDE and tried again we recieved the following error during the upload.

avrdude stk500_getsync() timeout communicating with programmer

**After some Googling we tried the following fixes:**

> 1. Remove all the `!!!` in the source code, Because of this the Mega
>      can enter some kind of safe mode
> 2. Tried a test sketch, Same error
> 3. When uploading a sketch presing the reset button on the board.
>
> Sometimes the PC could also not detect that the board was connected it
>   would not show up in the Device Manager. But when we re-connected the
>   USB it would pop-up in the Windows Device Manager,

We might think we corrupted the bootloader of the Arduino Mega because we unplugged the USB cable during flashing. Prehaps someone knows somehting else that might be wrong with our setup.

### Equipment used

- Lenovo Y50-70 running Windows 10 with the Arduino IDE
- Arduino Mega 2260 that was provided with the 3D-printer
- USB cable for connection between PC and Arduino
- [Firmware for the Printer](https://github.com/r0ndL/Tevo-Tarantula-Marlin-1.1-RC7-BugFix-)
- [Configuration Guide for the BL Touch](https://mon.im/2016/06/tevo-tarantula-bltouch-setup.html)

  ### Images

[image: IDE-Error]
[image: Arduino-Mega 2260]
[image: 3D-PrinterSetup]

Comment: You don't need a bootloader on the ATMega to work with avrdude. You can even use avrdude to load a new bootloader into your ATMega. **You will need an ATMega programmer, however**. After compiling your firmware with the Arduino IDE, you should be able to find something like `%TEMP%\arduino_build_...\Marlin.ino.with_bootloader.hex`. You should be able to program this file manually with avrdude _from the command line_. This will also repair any broken bootloader.